# Solutions to Multiple 70D Connected to a single computer?

Tags: tethering, file-transfer, canon-70d, eos-utility, wifi

My situation is I have 3-6 70D Canon Cameras on the floor depending on the event and would like to utilise the WIFI connection on these cameras but I have tried to work out a way to have Multiple Cameras connected to one computer.

The EOS Software is great as you can wirelessly tether 1 camera but you cannot ad any more cameras.

So I am looking for solutions to be able to add multiple cameras to one computer through WiFi. Even if there are programs that allow the cameras to send the photos directly to a folder through wifi on the computer would be great as the EOS Software is a full remote for the DSLR which I only use to have the images transferred.

Comment: can't find anything that supports wifi, digiCamControl (http://digicamcontrol.com/) and Breeze systems DSLR Remote Pro Multi-Camera (http://breezesys.com/MultiCamera/index.htm) both offer multiple camera controls but not wifi (according to the web site, never used any of them)

Comment: Thank you nir. I was thinking of being able to emulate multiple windows of the EOS Utility. Do you think this would work? Or even just creating a dropbox folder where the camera just dumps the images on there?

Comment: If you put multiple 70D's on the same wifi segment do they all show up as devices in Windows Explorer?  (If you even use Windows, that is.)  If that's the case you could avoid using it and use WIA instead.

Comment: James, Only one camera can be seen per computer. You need to go into the camera to pair it to a computer or the camera will not communicate without authorized pairing first hand.

Answer (score 2):

Canon has a good [Knowledge Base article](http://kbsupport.cusa.canon.com/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1011&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=false&TIMEZONE_OFFSET&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=61654) about connecting a camera to your WiFi network.  You should be able to repeat the steps for each camera, making sure each camera has a unique name, Step 2.5.  Be sure to select "Auto Setting" for "IP address set" unless you have a unique network topography.

You'll also probably want to change the download location for each camera to its own unique folder.  This is done in step 5.2

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of tethering directly to a single computer, you might have better luck setting each camera to upload images to a web service via [Canon Image Gateway](http://www.cig.usa.canon.com/cu/en_US/support.html_Photo_Album). It might not be ideal due to the upload step, but you'll be able to access photos coming from multiple cameras at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I can promise that it is very likely that it is *technically* possible. I do not know how *easy* it is, however. I do not know of ready-made solutions for this.

However, Canon published an [(ED)SDK](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/sdk_homepage) that can be used to remote-control EOS cameras; so I believe it to be possible to write an application that can speak to multiple connected cameras. There is a [CodeProject example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp) that uses the EDSDK and seems to be able to handle multiple connected cameras.

On another note, here is an overkill solution: If your PC is sufficiently powerful, you could run a virtual machine per camera and do some ingenious trickery with the routing to end up with only one camera per virtual PC – which the EOS software supports.

(Not really good solutions, but at least possible. :( )

Answer (score -2):

Apologizes for my initial answers check this link http://learn.usa.canon.com/app/pdfs/quickguides/WFT_EOS_Utility_OSX.pdf

How to connect your EOS cameras to a wifi network. It shows how it can be assigned an i/p address and subnet. Though it shows about 7D i tried it with 70D and it worked.Unfortunately i don't have multiple cameras to test connection with same network but it should be similar to multiple devices connecting to same network. I haven't tested whether i can control multiple devices using EOS utility. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: I think your analogy is broken. I don't want to talk on multiple wireless networks, I just want multiple devices to talk on the same network.

Comment: Multiple networks is easy (you just need a pile of usb Wi-Fi adapters) but you'd still be in the situation that the EOS utility will only talk to one camera.

Comment: First of all 70d doesn't join any wifi it creates it's own network to which devices join. James the link does explain why multiple wifi adapters won't work. Philip to add multiple devices on same network it might possible only if a IP address can be associated with it

Comment: @PrasadChuri Like the 6D, the 70D can *either* connect to an existing WiFi network or act as a WiFi access point itself.